# Discord Bot Say command Edit: With Permissions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I relatively new to javascript (.js) and would like some help with me latest discord bot.
Here is an example of the code i use:

```
  if (command === "ping") {
    msg.channel.send(`Pong! <@${msg.author.id}> my Ping is ` + bot.ping + `ms`);
  }
```

Thank you for reading this and i hope you can answer my question 
Edit:
My question depends on if you know discord.js well and if you know how to setup a .say command where it says the message i type in
Edit:
Also, to prevent people abusing, i would like to know if i can say you have to have a permission level of 8 to use this command and it will not work if it is below 8

Comment: Java and Javascript are different languages. It seems like you are working with Javascript, not Java.

Comment: Ok...but do you have an answer?

Comment: If you are using JQuery (or another technology like it), it may make sense to add the appropriate tag (such as `jquery` for JQuery).

Comment: Ok
Can you give me an example of the code please?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You should add that to the question itself, not just have it in a comment. You can edit your question to do that.

Comment: This is not clear enough to provide help

Comment: what i am trying to say is someting like this:
Me: .say Hi 
Bot: Hi

Comment: Can you post your full code of what you have already tried?

Comment: doesn't matter anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if(command === "say"){
     msg.channel.send(msg.content.substr(4));
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dLOv.png)

This only works if your prefix is 1 character long.
Your prefix is "." so it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that java and javascript are not the same language. You can read more about this here: [Differences between java and javascript](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Java-and-JavaScript)

Anyway, discord bots normally require a prefix to work properly and be aware when the message is directed to them or not, elsewhere they will send messages when they are not supposed to.

```js
const PREFIX = "." // set the prefix

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot is on');
}); // this will log a message when the event 'ready' is triggered

client.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.lenght).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]){
        case PREFIX+'ping':
            message.channel.send(`Pong! <@${msg.author.id}> my Ping is ${bot.ping}ms`);
            break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Command Ping

```js
client.on('message', async message =>{
  const prefix = "!";
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

 if(message.content === '!ping'){
    const msg = await message.channel.send("Checking for ping...") // Checking a message
    var ping = Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp + " ms";
    msg.edit("Pong ! " + message.member.user.tag + " my Ping is "`${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}` + " ms`");  
    // edit message from checking message to ping message
  };
});
```